# Java Scanner exception from unknown source during File I/O

Tags: java, exception

I am trying to play around with opening, closing, and writing to files. Whenever I try to open a file, if it doesn't exist at the path I provide the program tells me. If it exists, the program reads whatever is inside and displays it. If the user doesn't want to look for a file, there is an option to create a file and fill it with data.

It works so far except whenever I read a file, after it is successful in displaying the data I get an unknown source Scanner exception. Here is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class FileIO {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true){

            System.out.println("1. Load file from path of your choosing.");
            System.out.println("2. Answer eight questions and save the answers into a file.");
            System.out.println("3. Exit the program.");


            int userChoice = input.nextInt();

            switch (userChoice){
            case 1:
                loadFile();
                break;
            case 2:
                answerQuestions();
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Goodbye!");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void loadFile() throws IOException{
        System.out.println("What is the file name you want to try to read?");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        File f = new File(input.nextLine());
        if (f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()){
            System.out.println("The file exists!");
            Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(f);
            while (inputFile.hasNext()){
                String answer = inputFile.next();
                System.out.println(answer);
            }

            input.close();
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("File does not exist at that given path!");
        }

    }

    public static void answerQuestions() throws IOException{

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What is your name?"); // 1
        String name = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is your favorite color?"); // 2
        String color = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is your favorite type of music?"); // 3
        String music = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is your favorite place?"); // 4
        String place = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is your favorite food?"); // 5
        String food = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is your favorite book?"); // 6
        String book = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is your favorite programming language?"); // 7
        String language = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Do you prefer laptop or desktop computers?"); // 8
        String computer = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("All the questions are answered. Name the file you want to save the answers to: ");
        File f = new File(input.nextLine());
        if (f.exists()){
            System.out.println("File already exists!");
            return;
        }
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(f);
        output.print(name + "\n");
        output.print(color + "\n");
        output.print(music + "\n");
        output.print(place + "\n");
        output.print(food + "\n");
        output.print(book + "\n");
        output.print(language + "\n");
        output.print(computer + "\n");

        output.close();

    }
}
```

This is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at Lab4.main(Lab4.java:18)
```

What exactly is the problem? I tried changing the Scanner input on line 19 to input2 but that didn't work. The program lets me select as many menu options as I want if the file does not exist when checking a path, so I'm guessing something is wrong with the program at the part where it starts printing stuff to the console if a file is found. But I have no idea what it could be. I would appreciate any tips or hints that guide me towards handling this error. Thanks for your time.

Comment: And the exception is what?

Comment: Sorry about that, I added the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
/* other code here */
input.close();
```

Closing a Scanner also closes the stream it's using. You closed `System.in`. Just like any other stream, if it's closed, you can't use it.

The ideal solution would be to create a Scanner once (at the start of the program) and then use it every time you want to read input.

Comment: Thanks so much! So if I know I will be using a single Scanner for the same types of input, I can just create a single Scanner at the start...do what I need to do, and then close the scanner at the very end? What's the point of closing it if it's at the very end? Since the program ends anyway, is there any point to close the scanner?

Comment: If the program's about to end anyway, it won't make a difference whether you close the scanner. In fact, it probably won't make a difference even if the program isn't about to end. `Scanner.close` probably doesn't do anything apart from closing the stream (`System.in`).

Answer (score 0):

Remove `input.close();` from `loadFile()` function as it is closing referenced standard input stream blocking further IO.